# Deploy app via pipeline using ssh and PM2

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, pm2

I am using Gitlab CE for CI/CD, and I have a pipeline to deploy to an ubuntu server, which runs the apps with `pm2`. The actions are:

- Removes `/node_modules`, `/dist` and `/tmp` folders
- Pulls updated code
- Builds the code into `/dist`
- Removes the app from `pm2`
- Start the app with `pm2` again

Here is the pipeline:

```
image: node:16

before_script:
  - apt-get update -qq
  - apt-get install -qq git
  - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get install -qq openssh-client )'
  - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
  - ssh-add <(echo "$K8S_SECRET_SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | base64 -d)
  - ssh-add <(echo "$K8S_SECRET_SSH_PRIVATE_KEY_AWS" | base64 -d)
  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'

stages:
  - deploy_production

deploy_production:
  stage: deploy_production
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - ssh foo@example.com "cd /var/www/html/example2/example2.com && rm -rf node_modules dist/* tmp"
    - ssh foo@example.com "cd /var/www/html/example2/example2.com && git pull origin master"
    - ssh foo@example.com "source ~/.bash_profile && export NPM_TOKEN=${NPM_TOKEN} && export SECRET=${SECRET} && cd /var/www/html/example2/example2.com && nvm use --delete-prefix && git checkout master && npm ci --verbose && npm run prod"
    - ssh foo@example.com "cd /var/www/html/example2/example2.com && pm2 delete example2.com"
    - ssh foo@example.com "cd /var/www/html/example2/example2.com && export SECRET=${SECRET} && NODE_ENV=production pm2 start ./dist/server.js --name example2.com --update-env"
```

Now, when the job succeeds, if I enter the production server and list `pm2` instances I see:

```
┌─────┬───────────────┬─────────────┬─────────┬─────────┬──────────┬────────┬──────┬───────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ id  │ name          │ namespace   │ version │ mode    │ pid      │ uptime │ ↺    │ status    │ cpu      │ mem      │ user     │ watching │
├─────┼───────────────┼─────────────┼─────────┼─────────┼──────────┼────────┼──────┼───────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│ 80  │ example2.com  │ default     │ 0.0.1   │ fork    │ 3258598  │ 0s     │ 0    │ online    │ 0%       │ 13.7mb   │ foo      │ disabled │
└─────┴───────────────┴─────────────┴─────────┴─────────┴──────────┴────────┴──────┴───────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
```

But when I try to access the app, it is down.
Now, if I access via ssh directly and delete and start it manually, it will work:

```
ssh foo@example.com
$ pm2 delete example2.com
$ export SECRET=my_secret && NODE_ENV=production pm2 start ./dist/server.js --name example2.com --update-env
```

If someone has any idea why doing it directly it is working, but doing it via pipline is not, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

one thing you could double-check would be your user permissions that you are using inside the gitlab runner to ssh - are these creds different to the ones you use when doing it manually?

I would also suggest maybe changing your approach to how you are deploying to your production server. Keeping a copy of a git repo on it doesn't sound very safe to me. Instead, I would look to ship only the compiled binaries or dist folder in your case and **not** remotely run git based commands on another server.

You could also install a self-hosted gitlab runner directly onto your production server with limited user permissions for the gitlab-runner user, then creating a build job to generate and zip your dist folder from your project. Take this zipped folder as an artifact and then you can have another job on the production server to "unzip" and deploy with the correct user permissions.

what I mean by this is:

1. Install a self hosted gitlab (bash based would work fine) runner on your production server.
2. Edit your ci script to build your dist folder, zip it and store it as an artifact in gitlab.
3. Have a production job stage that will download the artifact (happens automatically within a pipeline) and unzip in the correct location
4. amend the user permissions with chmod to make sure the unzipped dist version of your app is owned by the correct user - for example if you are running nginx then the nginx user needs to own the files under the directory that you want to serve.

Hope the user permissions thing helps :)